# SQLAlchemy nearest datetime

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Is their any simple (fast) way to fetch a table and find the datetime nearest from a given dateTime in SQLAlchemy ? In most case the delta will be seconds between the datetime given and the one in the table.

The date column is the primary key

EDIT :
I'm using SQLite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is the primary key a simple "sort by diff ascending, fetch 1st row" might not be the fastest, though simple solution. A quick and dirty way could be to fetch a union of larger than and less than the given datetime, sorted ascending and descending and limited to 1st row, and then pick the one with the smaller diff from the 2.

Here's an example using Postgresql as backend and a test table with a year's worth of timestamps with 12s resolution:

```
sopython=> create table testi (key timestamp without time zone primary key);
CREATE TABLE
sopython=> insert into testi
select *
from generate_series(now() at time zone 'utc' - '1 year'::interval,
                     now() at time zone 'utc',
                     '12 seconds'::interval);
INSERT 0 2628001
```

and the Python:

```
In [29]: from sqlalchemy import union_all, case

In [30]: from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

In [31]: the_time = datetime(2016, 5, 5, 10, 45, 55)
```

Create the union that fetches the closest values, wrapping the subqueries in a SELECT statement, so that it works in SQLite as well, for example.

```
In [32]: greater = session.query(Testi).filter(Testi.key > the_time).\
    ...:     order_by(Testi.key.asc()).limit(1).subquery().select()

In [33]: lesser = session.query(Testi).filter(Testi.key <= the_time).\
    ...:     order_by(Testi.key.desc()).limit(1).subquery().select()

In [34]: the_union = union_all(lesser, greater).alias()
```

Alias the model to the result of the union

```
In [35]: testi_alias = aliased(Testi, the_union)
```

Calculate the difference from the given datetime

```
In [36]: the_diff = testi_alias.key - the_time
```

or in SQLite

```
In [36]: the_diff = func.julianday(testi_alias.key) - func.julianday(the_time)
```

Fetch the closer of the 2. The case monstrosity is for [getting the absolute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004806/remove-sign-from-interval) of the interval, in Postgresql. Other DBs require different solutions for the difference calculation and taking the absolute value. With SQLite simply `func.abs(the_diff)`.

```
In [37]: session.query(testi_alias).\
    ...:     order_by(case([(the_diff < timedelta(0), -the_diff)],
    ...:                   else_=the_diff)).\
    ...:     first()
Out[37]: <sqlalchemy.ext.automap.testi at 0x7f096f837828>

In [38]: _.key
Out[38]: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 5, 10, 45, 54, 855799)
```

While the simple solution of just ordering by diff and limiting ran in some *800ms* on this machine, the above query finishes in about *70-100ms*. If you double the data, the simple solution – relying on seq scan – doubles as well.

The union finds these two values from the table:

```
In [14]: session.query(testi_alias.key).all()
Out[14]: 
[(datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 5, 10, 45, 54, 855799)),
 (datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 5, 10, 46, 6, 855799))]
```

And finally, you can wrap it all up in a generic function:

```
def get_closest(session, cls, col, the_time):
    greater = session.query(cls).filter(col > the_time).\
        order_by(col.asc()).limit(1).subquery().select()

    lesser = session.query(cls).filter(col <= the_time).\
        order_by(col.desc()).limit(1).subquery().select()

    the_union = union_all(lesser, greater).alias()
    the_alias = aliased(cls, the_union)
    the_diff = getattr(the_alias, col.name) - the_time
    abs_diff = case([(the_diff < timedelta(0), -the_diff)],
                    else_=the_diff)

    return session.query(the_alias).\
        order_by(abs_diff.asc()).\
        first()

get_closest(session, Testi, Testi.key, the_time)
```

Comment: Is the use of select * from table where datetime > your_date_time limit 1;
select * from table where datetime < your_date_time limit 1; will have better performance ?

Comment: would i get the row or the time value ?

Comment: The 2 selects are the idea behind the solution, but not the complete solution. Note that the particular queries will not return the correct result, if the smallest difference is 0, since neither query has equality included. You can adapt the query to return either one.

Comment: actually it's return the row ? (This is what i need)

Comment: Yes, the current version returns the row.

Comment: when i do session.query(the_alias).all() i got an error "near UNION"

Comment: Please don't edit the question to include problems with the offered solution. Those belong to a new question, or we could try and resolve them in chat. The "error near UNION" is probably due to us using different DB backends. The DB you're using is something you should always include in these types of questions, or you'll get answers that will not work out of the box for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137062/discussion-between-timo-and-ilja-everila).

Answer (score 2):

With plain SQL you can do something like:

```
select * from table where datetime > your_date_time limit 1;
select * from table where datetime < your_date_time limit 1;
```

to get the first after and the first before your datetime, then calculate the difference and get the closest.

With SQLAlchemy you can probably write something similar using the `.limit` or `.filter` method

Comment: I need the row which match the nearest time not only the time

Comment: `select  *` return the complete row, not only the time

Answer (score 1):

Really dislike the other answers. Very hard to read or drop down to pure SQL which was not what the question was asking for

Simple solution:

- `Event` is the model name
- `Event.ts` is the datetime column name
- ts param is the query filter

```
def closest(ts):
    import math
    # find the closest events which are greater/less than the timestamp
    gt_event = Event.query.filter(Event.ts > ts).order_by(Event.ts.asc()).first()
    lt_event = Event.query.filter(Event.ts < ts).order_by(Event.ts.desc()).first()

    # find diff between events and the ts, if no event found default to infintiy
    gt_diff = (gt_event.ts - ts).total_seconds() if gt_event else math.inf
    lt_diff = (ts - lt_event.ts).total_seconds() if lt_event else math.inf

    # return the newest event if it is closer to ts else older event
    # if an event is None its diff will always be greater as we set it to infinity
    return gt_event if gt_diff < lt_diff else lt_event
```