# Django Queryset absolute value of the annotated field

Tags: django, django-queryset

How do I get the absolute value of the annotated field? I tried the code below but it did't work.

```
queryset.annotate(relevance=abs(F('capacity') - int( request.GET['capacity']) ) ).order_by('relevance')
```

**Error:**

`TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'CombinedExpression'`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try with  [func expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import Func, F

queryset.annotate(relevance=Func(F('capacity') - int(request.GET['capacity']), function='ABS'))
```

Comment: @T.Tokic this doesn't work with `.annotate(
                distance=Func(F('datetime') - datetime_goal, function='ABS')
            ).order_by(
                'distance'
            )`. It returns `ProgrammingError: function abs(interval) does not exist`

Comment: I never used ABS with the intervals but it seems there are some workarounds for that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004806/remove-sign-from-interval

Answer (score 1):

Using your own django function, you could do

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Func, Value

class ABS(Func):
    
    function = "ABS"

queryset.annotate(relevance=ABS(F('capacity') - Value(int(request.GET['capacity']))))
```