# How do I get the matching id for every record?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

My table is called `platform_statuses`, here is its schema:

```
CREATE TABLE platform_statuses (
    id SERIAL,
    account INTEGER REFERENCES users (id),
    time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    value_in_cents INTEGER NOT NULL,
    status INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (
        0 < status
        AND status < 4
    ) DEFAULT 2,
    -- 1: Active, 2: Suspended, 3: Market is closed
    open_trades INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And this is my query, I would like to also get the matching id for the returned records.

```
SELECT
    max(timediff),
    time :: date,
    account
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            time,
            account,
            abs(time - date_trunc('day', time + '12 hours')) as timediff
        FROM
            platform_statuses
    ) AS subquery
GROUP BY
    account,
    time :: date
```

Also note that the abs function you see in the query is a custom one I got off this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44787918/6878890). Here is its definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION abs(interval) RETURNS interval AS $ $
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN ($ 1 < interval '0') THEN - $ 1
        else $ 1
    END;

$ $ LANGUAGE sql immutable;
```

Comment: No point in ordering (ORDER BY) sub queries

Comment: I also love postgresql enumerations for your "status" field.

Comment: You're completely right on the order by part, it was left accidentally in after tinkering with it for a while before giving up and posting the question. As for the enumeration part, you are completely right, it's what I had done originally, but unfortunately it needs to be accessed by ODBC in Access, and it has no enumeration support (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that, for each account and day, you want the record with the greatest `timediff`. If so, you can use `distinct on()` directly on your existing subquery:

```
select distinct on (account, time::date)
    id,
    time,
    account,
    abs(time - date_trunc('day', time + '12 hours')) as timediff
from platform_statuses
order by account, time::date, timediff desc
```

Comment: Thanks, this is absolutely what I needed. Brilliant. Also, you answered really quickly, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
select * from platform_statuses
where abs(time - date_trunc('day', time + '12 hours')) =
(
   select max(abs(time - date_trunc('day', time + '12 hours'))) 
   from platform_statuses
)
```